# ArcPy command to remove empty layers that are grouped

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, mxd, group-layer, remove

I have a script that works for MXD with ungrouped layers.

How can I change this so it works if there are groups of layers?

I have an MXD template with many layers & groups. The underlaying file GDB might have some feature classes empty. In that case I want to delete the layers and layer groups that are empty.

```py
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('current')
for df in arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd):
    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(df):
        print lyr
        if lyr.supports("dataSource"):
            result = arcpy.GetCount_management(lyr.dataSource)
            count = int(result.getOutput(0))
            print count            
            if count == 0:
                arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df,lyr)
            else:
                result_lyr = arcpy.GetCount_management(lyr)
                count_lyr = int(result.getOutput(0))
                print count_lyr
                if count_lyr == 0:
                    arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df,lyr)
mxd.save()
del mxd
```

Comment: What if one layer in a group is empty but the other layers in that group arent, what should happen then?

Comment: If one layer in a group is empty and the others aren't, the empty layer should be removed and the others should stay.

Comment: Your logic appears to be flawed, you get a layer from the map, if it supports datasource you continue. You get a count on its featureclass, if zero you remove the layer from map. If not zero you then get a count on the layer which logically must be not zero as the layer is pointing to the featureclass which logically if you are in that part of the code must be not zero so count_lyr will never be zero.

Comment: @Hornbydd Layer definitions include a Definition Query, so even if the source has records, it's possible that the layer on that source does not. In the end, the source count is not relevant, only the layer count, and only if its source not being actively edited,

Comment: Good point about the layer having a potential definition query but as there is no comments in the code that specify that scenario is relevant I would say you might get into a situation of not knowing if there are no records because the featureclass has none or the layer if filtering them out unless it is also testing if a definition query is being applied. We see no evidence that is being tested for in the code provided. Basically more comments in code is always a good thing!

Comment: @Vince yes, that is exactly my scenario - the layer source feature class might have features but the layer might not (there is a definition query on the layer to filter some features out).  The code above works well if the layers aren't grouped which is not in my case - I have a few group levels with subgroups. I am stuck now with my code

Answer (score 0):

For group layers, you can use isGroupLayer to test then iterate over to check for 0 counts...

https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/layer-class.htm

```
if lyr.isGroupLayer == True:
    for g_lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(lyrFile):
     ....
        if count_lyr == 0:
            arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df,g_lyr)
```